# What is the correct sql script for this select Statement?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2000, pivot

This is my script

```
SELECT iBranch_num,
   CASE WHEN iPatient_typ=1 THEN COUNT(iPatient_num) ELSE 0 END AS [New Patient], 
   CASE WHEN iPatient_typ=2 THEN COUNT(iPatient_num) ELSE 0 END AS [Buying Patient],                
   CASE WHEN iPatient_typ=3 THEN COUNT(iPatient_num) ELSE 0 END AS [Active Patient],
   CASE WHEN iPatient_typ=4 THEN COUNT(iPatient_num) ELSE 0 END AS [Inactive Patient]
FROM tblsotransaction
WHERE iStatus_typ=1
   AND iApply_dt BETWEEN 20130401 AND 20130408 
   AND iBranch_num=14
GROUP BY iBranch_num, iPatient_typ
```

Current Result:

```
14, 25, 0,  0,  0
14, 0,  8,  0,  0
14, 0,  0,  97, 0
14, 0,  0,  0,  2
```

I want the result to be like this

```
14, 25, 8,  9,  2
```

Comment: What RDBMS you are using? is it SQL server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap the whole `CASE` expression inside an aggregate function `COUNT`, and remove `iPatient_typ` from the `GROUP BY` clause:

```
SELECT 
  iBranch_num,
  COUNT(CASE WHEN iPatient_typ=1 THEN iPatient_num ELSE 0 END) AS [New Patient], 
  COUNT(CASE WHEN iPatient_typ=2 THEN iPatient_num ELSE 0 END) AS [Buying Patient],                
  COUNT(CASE WHEN iPatient_typ=3 THEN iPatient_num ELSE 0 END) AS [Active Patient],
  COUNT(CASE WHEN iPatient_typ=4 THEN iPatient_num ELSE 0 END) AS [Inactive Patient]
FROM tblsotransaction
WHERE iStatus_typ = 1 
  AND iApply_dt BETWEEN 20130401 AND 20130408 
  AND iBranch_num = 14
GROUP BY iBranch_num;
```

**Or:** `SUM`:

```
SELECT 
  iBranch_num,
  SUM(CASE WHEN iPatient_typ = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [New Patient], 
  SUM(CASE WHEN iPatient_typ = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [Buying Patient],
  SUM(CASE WHEN iPatient_typ = 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [Active Patient],
  SUM(CASE WHEN iPatient_typ = 4 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [Inactive Patient]
FROM tblsotransaction
WHERE iStatus_typ = 1 
  AND iApply_dt BETWEEN 20130401 AND 20130408 
  AND iBranch_num = 14
GROUP BY iBranch_num;
```

Comment: I got same result with this acript

Comment: @odlanyer - Sorry, remove `iPatient_typ` from the `GROUP BY` clause, I updated my answer.

Comment: Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery.

Comment: on your 2nd answer it has a correct result but the counting is tripled!